# How to make multitouch working in android?

Tags: java, android, multi-touch, touch-event

I'm creating a Pong game in android and I have a problem with multitouch

To move my two players, I'm using onTouchEvent method, and both of players can be moved in the same time. There is one problem : if the last finger down on the screen is not the first up, I have an Exception because the pointerId of the remaining finger is equals to pointerCount and my game exits. And I have to use onTouchEvent method to get coordonates x and y of all fingers on the screen.

```
 @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int actionPerformed = event.getAction();
        switch(actionPerformed) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
                for(int i=0; i<pointerCount; i++) {
                    int x = (int) event.getX(event.getPointerId(i));
                    int y = (int) event.getY(event.getPointerId(i));
                    if(y<this.height/2-joueur1.getRayon()-1) { joueur1.setX(x); joueur1.setY(y); }
                    else if(y>this.height/2+joueur2.getRayon()+1){ joueur2.setX(x); joueur2.setY(y); }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
        return true;
    }
//This is the message shown when I'm releasing a finger which is not the last one down

E/MotionEvent-JNI: An exception occurred: pointerCount 1, pointerIndex 1.
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pong, PID: 29258
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
        at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
```

If anyone can help me to resolve my problem, I would be grateful. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track the touch events from multiple pointers you have to use `theMotionEvent.getActionIndex()` and `theMotionEvent.getActionMasked()` methods to identify the index of the pointer and the touch event which happened for this pointer.

This pointer index can change over time, e.g. if one finger is lifted from the device. The stable version of a pointer is the pointer id, which can be determined with `thegetPointerId(pointerIndex)` method from the `MotionEvent` object.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
 { 
 // get pointer index from the event object int
  pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
// get pointer ID 
 int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
// get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
 int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();
 switch (maskedAction) 
       { 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
             { 
                // TODO use data break;
             }
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           {
           // a pointer was moved 
          // TODO use data break;
            } 
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:       
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
           { 
            // TODO use data break; 
           }
      } 
 invalidate(); 
 return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, but I still have this problem using getActionMasked() and getActionIndex()... This is my new code :

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //Detection du nombre de doigts sur l'écran et deplacement des joueurs en fonction de la position des doigts
        int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
        for(int i=0; i<pointerCount; i++) {
            int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            int pointerId    = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

            switch(maskedAction) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int x = (int) event.getX(pointerId);
                    int y = (int) event.getY(pointerId);

                    this.posX = x; this.posY = y;

                    //Déplacement du joueur 1
                    if (posX >= joueur1.getX()-joueur1.getRayon() && posX <= joueur1.getX()+joueur1.getRayon()
                        && posY >= joueur1.getY()-joueur1.getRayon() && posY <= joueur1.getY()+joueur1.getRayon()
                        && posY < this.height/2-joueur1.getRayon()) {

                        joueur1.setX(posX);
                        joueur1.setY(posY);
                    }
                    //Déplacement du joueur 2
                    if (posX >= joueur2.getX()-joueur2.getRayon() && posX <= joueur2.getX()+joueur2.getRayon()
                            && posY >= joueur2.getY()-joueur2.getRayon() && posY <= joueur2.getY()+joueur2.getRayon()
                            && posY > this.height/2+joueur2.getRayon()) {

                        joueur2.setX(posX);
                        joueur2.setY(posY);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return true;
```

Do I need to use for loop to make multitouch working ? Because only one player can be moved if I don't do this.